# python and telethon exception Request was unsuccessful 6 time(s)

Tags: python, telethon

I have a script where messages from telegram are read and processed. 
There is also a simple GUI which shows a list of available channels/chats.

I'm testing it on various computers and different phone numbers/clients.

Only in 1 case, just one, when 1 message is received I get this exception (which also freezes the GUI, but this is another problem)

```
2020-03-25 12:59:58,985 :  Unhandled exception on on_msg_received
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\telethon\client\updates.py", line 428, in _dispatch_update
File "tele_test.py", line 963, in on_msg_received
File "site-packages\telethon\requestiter.py", line 75, in __anext__
File "site-packages\telethon\client\dialogs.py", line 53, in _load_next_chunk
File "site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 108, in __call__
ValueError: Request was unsuccessful 6 time(s)
```

any idea what could be the cause?

thanks

this is the code section where the problem happens:

```
async def on_msg_received( self, event ):   
    now = datetime.now()
    hour = now.hour
    minute = now.minute

    chat_name = ''
    async for dialog in self.cl.iter_dialogs():
        if( dialog.id == event.chat_id ):
            chat_name = dialog.name

    logging.warning('------- chat = %s', chat_name )
    t = event.raw_text
```

where line 963 showed in the error is:

```
async for dialog in self.cl.iter_dialogs():
```

Comment: Telegram may have internal issues, in which case the request will fail a lot.

Comment: @Lonami thanks for your answer. so in this case the issue is not my software but telegram on that account? That would explain why on the others I don't have any issue..

Comment: Yes, most likely is an error on the server.